# jQuery suddenly not working properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I had a working piece of jQuery for a while but all of the sudden it doesn't work anymore. This is the original (working) piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#partial_button').click(function(){
    $('#partial_form').show();
    $('#partial_button').hide();
  });
});
```

Now it doesn't even go into the document ready. To make it work I have to do this:

```
//$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#partial_button').live("click", function(){
  //$('#partial_button').click(function(){
    $('#partial_form').show();
    $('#partial_button').hide();
  });
//});
```

So basically I have to disable the document ready and change the click into a live click to make it work. I am clueless why this has happened, nothing else changed. Any ideas?

Edit: version is 1.8.3, but it also happens on 2.0

Comment: so even if you do just `$(document).ready( function() { alert("Hello"); });`, you get nothing?

Comment: Do you know which commit of yours is the culprit? If so, I'd do a `git show` on that commit for clues. If not, I'd do a `git bisect` to identify the culprit.

Comment: @JasonSwett This isn't a `git` question...

Comment: Trying to help him figure out what changed, since according to his question, he has no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the page might still be loading something in the background, preventing `$(document).ready();` from firing. Check for resources that aren't loading.

Comment: I checked but all resources are loaded